# How to create partitons while installing Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, partitioning

I have windows 7. I want to install ubuntu 12.04 into my system in a separate partition. I had made four partitions in windows:

> windows(100gb) 
>   
> ubuntu(98.5gb)
>   
> personal(500gb,logical)

Note: all are ntfs partions.

I want ubuntu to be installed in partion ubuntu created by me. Can anyone give a detailed procedure of how to do it. Ubuntu and windows partion are primary, NTFS partitions. My ram is 8gb.

Comment: Easiest would be to delete the Ubuntu partition from Windows (i.e. leave it **unpartitioned**) to let the installer choose this partition for a dual boot install. Here are more details (for XP but the Ubuntu part is the same): http://askubuntu.com/questions/6486/how-to-dual-boot-with-windows-xp-and-partition

Comment: That's probably a good idea.  I tend to think of how to do things in Ubuntu, and forget that Windows can actually do things too. :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you created the partition already, but it is NTFS?

I think I would run "gparted" from the installation CD/USB, as it will graphically display your disk layout, and allow you to change it.  You will need to choose "sda" from the drop-down list on the right, which would default to the current disk, the CD or USB stick.

Once you have the hard disk displayed, find the Ubuntu partition, and click on it.  It should highlight that partition in the list below; note the name in the first column, which will be something like "/dev/sda2", or possibly a higher number.  This is the Linux method of specifying disks, because the filesystem is mounted to a directory in "/dev".

You then right-click on that entry in the list, and choose "format to", then choose "ext4".  To actually apply this operation, you will click on the green checkmark to the right of the icons in the toolbar, or use the menu "Edit -> apply".  This step may not be required, but I'm not sure if you can re-format during the install.

You also need a small swap drive, probably about 5 GB or so.  I'd resize the last partition to reduce it by that much, to create a blank partition at the end of the drive.  You can also delete the Ubuntu partition, then create a new partition that is 5 GB smaller, and create another after it formatted as swap.

Once this is done, click on the icon on the desktop to install Ubuntu, and when you get to the disk partitioning section, choose "Something Else" for Manual Partitioning.  Then choose the partition you formatted.  The questions are fairly straight-forward, except perhaps the one that says "Use As", where you enter or select from the lis "/" for the main filesystem, and for the swap drive, you can select "swap" from the list.

I'm probably a bit vague because I don't remember the exact wording.  This part is close to the start of the install, so if you get stuck, you can always stop and ask questions.

Comment: i tried to install ubuntu.After inserting the cd i selected that do something else option button.
it then directed me to partition editor,where i gave 8 gb for swapping and left 90gb for mounting to /
i din leave any empty space.But it was unsucessful as i guess it wasnt primary partition.Now i changed it to primary partition.Can i follow the same procedure or as u asked leave some empty space after swap partiton(y is there a need for dis empty space.)if so how much should i give.
I don have an idea about using gparted

Comment: Primary partitions are actually **not** recommended, except for Windows.  Logical drives are more flexible, and suitable for any Linux distro I've used.  I have absolutely no primary partitions on my system with several Linux distros.  It would be good to know what the error said.  It may have been something simple, like leaving out one parameter. Perhaps you could read the [Ubuntu Installation Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/i386/index.html) for more info.